# Replace attributes in Data Class objects

Tags: python, python-3.7, python-dataclasses

I'd like to replace the attributes of a [dataclass](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/) instance, analogous to `namedtuple._replace()`, i.e. making an altered copy of the original object:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from collections import namedtuple

U = namedtuple("U", "x")

@dataclass
class V:
    x: int

u = U(x=1)
u_ = u._replace(x=-1)
v = V(x=1)

print(u)
print(u_)
print(v)
```

This returns:

```
U(x=1)
U(x=-1)
V(x=1)
```

How can I mimic this functionality in dataclass objects?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The `dataclasses` module has a helper function for field replacement on instances ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.replace))

```
from dataclasses import replace
```

Usage differs from `collections.namedtuple`, where the functionality was provided by a method on the generated type (*Side note:* [`namedtuple._replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._replace) is documented/public API, using an underscore on the name was called a "regret" by the author, see link at end of answer).

```
>>> from dataclasses import dataclass, replace
>>> @dataclass
... class V:
...     x: int
...     y: int
...     
>>> v = V(1, 2)
>>> v_ = replace(v, y=42)
>>> v
V(x=1, y=2)
>>> v_
V(x=1, y=42)
```

For more background of the design, see the PyCon 2018 talk - [Dataclasses: The code generator to end all code generators](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-TwcmT6Rcw).  The `replace` API is discussed in depth, along with other design differences between `namedtuple` and `dataclasses`, and some performance comparisons are shown.

Comment: It seems like someone discovered issues with `init` and post-init hooks in dataclasses, and instead of revisiting the design and resolving complexity, they chose to solve it just by adding complexity. The real story is that if you are leveraging dataclasses in some way where they aren't treated as completely logic-free containers, you're using them wrong and you need a different tool. `deepcopy` of a dataclass, for example, should have absolutely zero risk of doing anything besides simplistic deepcopy of each member attribute, so there is no least surprise issue for the user.

Comment: `replace` is pretty useful when having (pseudo-)immutable objects, such as frozen dataclasses. They are very common in functional programming where you don't mutate the original object, but instead return a new object with all fields equal except the ones you `replace`.

Comment: I sort of want to have replacec as `method` rather than a function, because it seems like it embeds the assumption that something is a dataclass in calling code.

Comment: @ely I disagree with your claim that dataclasses must be completely logic-free containers. Consider a frozen dataclass modeling a 2D triangle, for example, where you might want a method for computing the area, and validation that the triangle is not degenerate (no collinear vertices). What better place to put the validation than in a post-init hook?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with this? @AttRigh

`def replace(self, **kwargs): return dataclasses.replace(self, **kwargs)`

Comment: @wim and @hugovdberg coming back to this a long time later. Wim, validation logic like that ought never be internal to the container itself. Make a helper function, `validate_triangle` - don't bloat a simple record object with responsibilities for self processing. If you need it for some (dubious) OO reason, then use a class. Almost _any_ place would be better for that validation logic than as part of obtuse instance creation of something any user of such an object is likely to assume is just a basic data record. It reminds of `@property`, which is also frequently a bad choice & overused.

Comment: In other words, if you need a "smart object" or are worried about invalid states being unrepresentable through hidden magic transparent to a user of the structures, that's exactly a situation where dataclass is not for you. In fact, seeing `@dataclass` would be like a bright billboard advertising "No funny business going on behind the scenes here! Just a super simple record type!"

Comment: @ely That is how you see it, but I don't read a reason. For me, dataclasses are a power- and beautiful way to avoid boiler plate code around initialization, access and contracts of attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Just using replace will have reference pointer to previous mutable objects,  hence two instances of a dataclass will share a state

So try something like this:

```py
@dataclasses.dataclass(frozen=True)
class MyDataClass:
    mutable_object: list
    val: int
    
    def copy(self, **changes):
        return dataclasses.replace(deepcopy(self), **changes)

data = MyDataClass([], 1)
data2 = data.copy(val=2)
assert data.mutable_object != data2.mutable_object
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you mean by the reference pointer to a mutable object? When is this important?

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is about `dataclass`, but if you're using `attr.s` instead then you can use [`attr.evolve`](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/api.html#attr.evolve) instead of `dataclasses.replace`:

```py
import attr

@attr.s(frozen=True)
class Foo:
    x = attr.ib()
    y = attr.ib()

foo = Foo(1, 2)
bar = attr.evolve(foo, y=3)
```

Answer (score -1):

`dataclass` is just syntactic sugar for the automatic creation of a special `__init__` method and a host of other "boilerplate" methods based on type-annotated attributes.

Once the class is created, it is like any other, and its attributes can be overwritten and instances can be copied, e.g.

```
import copy

v_ = copy.deepcopy(v)
v_.x = -1
```

Depending on what the attributes are, you may only require `copy.copy`.

Comment: –1 It is incorrect to use a copy/deepcopy for field replacement on dataclasses.  In some complex use cases (e.g. init/post_init hooks), data may not be handled correctly.  The better way is to use `dataclasses.replace()` function.

Comment: @wim revisiting this a bit later I think my disagreement about `replace` is even stronger after having dealt with this feature in production systems for a while. I added some comments to your answer for a different take. I totally respect your POV is different, but I wanted to highlight a dissenting opinion because some users may feel like I do, and it could inform them on ways to use convention based restrictions of `dataclass` that allow for avoiding the bad code smell of `replace`.

Comment: The suggested approach of making a copy and then setting attributes **does not work at all in the case of frozen dataclasses**, which are pretty common when you want hashable instances that can be stored inside sets or used as dictionary keys.

Comment: A frozen dataclass in Python is just a fundamentally confused concept. It could still have mutable attributes like lists and so on. Using such a thing for dict keys is a hugely bad idea.

Answer (score -2):

```
@dataclass()
class Point:
    x: float = dataclasses.Field(repr=True, default=0.00, default_factory=float, init=True, hash=True, compare=True,
                                 metadata={'x_axis': "X Axis", 'ext_name': "Point X Axis"})
    y: float = dataclasses.Field(repr=True, default=0.00, default_factory=float, init=True, hash=True, compare=True,
                                 metadata={'y_axis': "Y Axis", 'ext_name': "Point Y Axis"})

Point1 = Point(13.5, 455.25)
Point2 = dataclasses.replace(Point1, y=255.25)

print(Point1, Point2)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you add some text to your answer to explain how it solves the problem, and maybe also point our how it adds to the other answers already provided?